# Problem using Nodejs / Express routing paths

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am a long time programmer but I'm new to Node and have a simple question about routing paths in Express which I cannot get to the bottom of.

I've developed a very simple app using node/express and MySql. I have then split up my GET and POST routes in the app just for convenience. I am using the route '/posts' at the app level and the sub route '/submit-form' in my router() which is the URL my form submits to.

I'm obviously doing something stupid because it doesn't work, I get the cannot POST message. If I use the full URL in the app and in the router then it works fine so there's nothing wrong with the code I think, only with my understanding of how express does routing.

Any advice appreciated.

[image: Here is the app]
[image: Here is the route]
[image: Here is the form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A router should be used with the `.use()` method. Therefore, you should use the following in your app.js file

```
app.use('/posts', PostRoute)
```

When the nested router (on  `/posts`) will handle the request, it will now based on the nested route declaration which HTTP method should match

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
const app = express();
app.use('/user', require('./routes/user'))
```

then inside the user;

```
const router = express.Router({});
router.post('/login', (req,res,next) => {
});
module.exports = router;
```